# Rename script deleting images instead of renaming them

Tags: rust

I want to remove the `_` from the name of png images in a folder:

```
use std::error::Error;
use std::fs;
use std::path::Path;

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let dir = Path::new("/home/alex/Desktop");
    for entry in fs::read_dir(dir)? {
        let entry = entry?;
        let path = entry.path();
        if path.is_file() && path.extension().unwrap_or_default() == "png" {
            if let Some(Some(new_path)) = path
                .file_name()
                .map(|name| name.to_str().map(|s| s.replace("_", "")))
            {
                fs::rename(path, new_path)?;
            }
        }
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

The code is "deleting" the png files instead of renaming them. I suspect it's because they are being renamed to a location that doesn't exist. But I'm not quite sure how to modify the code to fix that.

Live code: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=323f901e4f0f4c99dbf5affeb0127991

Comment: Didn't try but it seems like your new path is just a file name instead of the full path right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code just uses the file name as new path, what you want to do is use `with_path_name` to replace the filename of `path` with your new file name:

```rust
use std::error::Error;
use std::fs;

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    for entry in fs::read_dir("/home/alex/Desktop")? {
        let path = entry?.path();
        if path.is_file() && path.extension().unwrap_or_default() == "png" {
            if let Some(new_name) = path
                .file_name()
                .and_then(|name| name.to_str())
                .map(|s| s.replace("_", ""))
            {
                let new_path = path.with_file_name(new_name);
                fs::rename(path, new_path)?;
            }
        }
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to prevent so much nesting?